# Why is a broken LCD tv causing the electrical circuit to go out without tripping a breaker?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, television

I live in a new apartment (about two years old), and have lived there for about two months without any electrical issues. I have an older 40 inch  1080p LCD tv (about 7-8 years old) in our bedroom (the bedroom is on the same electrical circuit as our bathroom). The other day, I went to turn on the tv and the picture was out. I just assumed the bulb or something finally went, but I know this can be caused by other issues.

In going to troubleshoot, I unplugged the tv and plugged it back in (it's plugged in directly into an outlet, along with an Amazon Firestick), as soon as I did this, the rest of the power on the same circuit went out (lights wouldn't turn on in bedroom/bathroom, no other outlet was supplying power, and the outlet in question also stopped providing power as well.) What's weird is that this didn't trip the breaker.

The apartment maintenance came and said it's because the tv was pulling too much power, so simply unplugging it brought power back to the the circuit. I tried the tv on other outlets and it didn't cause this issue (the tv bulb is still seemingly dead, but power on the tv works), and other electronics on the same outlet didn't cause this issue either. I also had like maybe one other small device on the same circuit at the time so I can't imagine it would be overloaded. I have little to no electrical knowledge (clearly), but I didn't think a device could somehow cut power to the rest of the circuit without tripping a breaker, especially an LCD tv, malfunctioning or not.

I'm beginning to wonder now too if the tv issue was a result of something electrical (a chicken or the egg scenario I suppose). there were no power surges or anything else unusual occurring ahead of time. I guess I'm just trying to feel out if this sounds like a normal occurrence, because I'd hate to buy a new tv and have it turn out that the electrical circuit is the cause of the original tv going out, and have the same thing happen again.

Thanks in advance for an electrical knowledge or insight.

Comment: The maintenance yahoo is wrong. A device can't "pull too much power" in the sense that it hogs it from the other devices. If the breaker isn't tripped, the other devices _will_ function, assuming that there isn't a faulty connection on the circuit. This is what I suspect (along with a bad TV backlight). Hard to say, though.

Comment: If the rest of the devices went off it *must* have tripped *something*. Either an MCB, the main breaker or a GFCI. As @isherwood says - maintenance guy knows not what he is talking about.

Comment: Look at the outlets that lost power to see if any have a "test or reset" button.  Maybe the maintenance guy reset it and didn't mention it to you.

Comment: Have you tried plugging a lamp into that outlet? It sounds to me like a loose connection to the outlet which is also breaking the connection to the rest of the circuit.

Comment: As the others have said, there is nothing that would disconnect and then reset automatically on its own without manual intervention, it would be illegal. So it's either a loose connection, probably in that receptacle, or you have what's called an "AFCI" receptacle and he hit the Reset button on the front. If you don't see a Test and Reset button on the front of the receptacle, then it's a loose connection. Loose connections are potential fire hazards, keep after him to not be lazy about it...

Comment: Yeah, I can’t get the problem to replicate with another device on the same outlet or anywhere else in that circuit. Even when I plug the tv into the specific outlet, it doesn’t always have the above issue. I was afraid it might be a connection issue. So then, how do I approach property management with this concern to get them to actually take it seriously? It’s tough because everything goes through general on-site maintenance team so trying to tell them I need someone to look into the electrical, they’re just going to send the maintenance guy again. Who won’t do anything.

Comment: I would try a heavy load like a hair dryer on high. Yes there are devices that can monitor power and shut the line down if excessive current draw is detected. I have seen these on equipment but not in residential units. If power is included they could be controlling it but I would go with a bad connection and a hair dryer plus your other devices should load the circuit enough to create the failure if it is loose (and it will get worse as each time there is usually some arcing)

Comment: Quick update: I had maintenance come back but shocker, they still claim nothing is wrong. They say they’re coming back tomorrow to replace the outlet anyways. Afterwards, I finally got the problem to consistently replicate with any combination of devices. It appears to trigger once both plugs are used. It doesn’t matter the device or the voltage. It’s literally any two devices, as soon as the second device gets plugged in that outlet, the whole circuit goes out.

Comment: @Jim -- post that as an answer and I'll give you a +1 for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 on GFCI , being an older tv , looks like you have an increase in leakage current on that tv.Could be caused by alot of things going faulty.

What you can do:
Basically go the circuit panel turn it off (to see which devices are connected)and start unplugging all devices on that circuit and see if it still trips with ONLY the TV connected to verify its the TV.This is  because the typical leakage current tolerance is ~20-30mA from A->N on gfci(depends on manufacturer and rating) for ALL devices on that circuit.Each device has a certain leakage current ,could be powerboards(surge protection type) , failing x/y caps ,etc..

But yeah going by gut feeling looks like someones going TV shopping for Christmas :)

Edit: Third paragraph of the OP indicates he's essentially done the trouble shooting you're recommending and that didn't help him out at all.

True ,need sleep :P , therein lies the answer,there is no way to fix leakage current unless you can internally repair the circuit board , so solution is to either get new tv or disassemble tv and find faulty module and replace accordingly.

Comment: Third paragraph of the OP indicates he's essentially done the trouble shooting you're recommending and that didn't help him out at all.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help and comments everyone! So they came back and discovered surprise surprise, it was a loose wire in that specific outlet. So it wasn’t specific to the tv. Still trying to figure out if that actually caused the tv to go bad though. Will be kind of annoyed, but not much I can do about it ‍♂️ They fixed the outlet and the problem seems to have resolved now.